# Mobile app for push notifications to a group

Tags: android, iphone-app, notification

I'm looking for a mobile app/service, where I could create a "channel", shared a link or something, and anyone could join the channel. everyone should be able to post. and every member of the channel would receive an push notification with full text (no need to photos, etc.). I guess some ability to moderate or pre-moderate would be nice, to manage spam.

anyone knows of a similar program?

Comment: Just check this app **[teamchat](http://www.teamchat.com/)**